Bound of operator norm for Gaussian ensemble (wainwright example 6.2)
Consider $W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ generated with i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ entries, theorem 6.1 in the Martin Wainwright HDS implies that
$$
\frac{\sigma_\max(W)}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 1 + \delta + \sqrt{\frac{d}{n}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\sigma_\min(W)}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 1 - \delta - \sqrt{\frac{d}{n}}
$$
where both bounds hold with probability greater than $1 - 2 e^{-n\delta^2/2}$.
The example 6.2 in wainwright claims that these bounds on the singular values of $W$ implies that
$$
||\frac{1}{n} W^TW - I_d||_2 \leq 2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{d}{n}} + \delta \right)+ \left(\sqrt{\frac{d}{n}} + \delta \right)^2.
$$
with probability greater than $1 - 2e^{-n\delta^2/2}$.
Why is this true?
